# Which laptops are appropriate to set a dual boot system (Windows and Linux)?

Tags: laptop, linux, windows

I'm looking for a laptop that can boot into at least two different systems in the way where I don't need to worry about future/sudden issues. However, I'll need to buy a high performance laptop with the following minimum requirements:

> - CPU: Intel i7- 8th generation
> - GPU: GTX 1050ti ( at least 4GB)
> - RAM: 16GB DDR4 2666Mhz
> - SSD: M.2 / NVMe
> - OS: Windows 10
> - M.2 with or without SATA 3 space: at least 2TB available to upgrade
> - Price limit: $2200
> - Laptops with good finish is better

Please, give me a list of the best laptops that you've found. Thanks :)

Ps: I'll install Ubuntu and thinking about one more distro too, setting a triboot system maybe.

**NOTICE**: I'm from Brazil and live here, at the moment I've found some laptops available in my country that I'm interested in, such as Dell G5 5590 and Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315 (but I don't know if they'll run Linux distros smooth with a dual/triple boot system). However I can take a risk and buy imported Dell G7 7590, for example, if Dell Brasil doesn't sell products like this until March.

**ADVICE**: Just tell me what are the best laptops (hardwares) models, as it is a hardware recommendation topic. Some brands doesn't allow the owner to install Linux OS on its laptops and if someone do it they alert about possible damages that brick the HARDWARE.

Comment: [Pretty much any consumer grade computer system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo) is capable of multi-boot given you have space to partition sections of your hard drive for it. Usually what is more of a concern is Linux driver support, but even then that usually isn't much of an issue with common consumer grade parts. If you give a target price limit, desired hard drive space, and location (for availability, country should do) I can try and maximize specs at the price point for you.

Comment: @BennettYeo Just updated my question! Thanks for your tips.

Comment: @BennettYeo Samsung Odyssey 2 might brick if you set multi-boot. Windows and BIOS are closest in this laptop than the majority. Caution! After Windows updates this laptop have a high risk to be bricked. So,for me this laptop is one of the not capables to multi-boot. The manual's page 6 warns the consumer about it: http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=US&CttFileID=7161023&CDCttType=UM&ModelType=C&ModelName=NP800G5M-X02US&VPath=UM/201811/20181105091028017/Win10_Manual_ENG.pdf

Comment: All the major brands you mentioned above are capable of multi-booting. In fact the Samsung laptop you mentioned is the only time I've ever heard of a laptop bricking from having multi boot installed.

Comment: @J-Mello: You misunderstood the manual. In the Samsung Odyssey, Windows is _not_ especially close to the BIOS. If you know what you're doing, it's fine to install Linux, even though it may void your warranty. Please see the answers to: ["Installing a second OS carries a risk of data loss; even your PC's user manual says so. If you have backups, is it now okay to install a second OS?"](https://superuser.com/questions/1512837/installing-a-second-os-carries-a-risk-of-data-loss-even-your-pcs-user-manual-s)

Comment: @BennettYeo: The Samsung laptop will _not_ be bricked if you install Linux. J-Mello merely misunderstood the manual. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @unforgettableidSupportsMonica I talked with a Samsung's employee,and he said that this process can damage the laptop. I read a lot about second boot in any laptop with Windows,and the main reason that the laptop can't boot (in Windows)is the changes that the user may do in a Windows' boot partition. Indeed, I don't got it at all but the employee used exactly these terms(damage the computer) to describe what might happens with the laptop.

Comment: Important: I recorded my conversation with the employee and,after read again,I missed he emphasized that the errors comes while the user do the installation. About Windows updates,I commented it here because I asked him about damages after Windows updates.However,as he asked me too,the update errors after the installation may happens indeed.

Comment: @J-Mello: If you make mistakes while trying to install Linux, you can indeed accidentally wipe the pre-installed Windows partition; but it's possible to deal with this mistake by reinstalling Windows. The harm is software-only harm. Linux installation mistakes will _not_ damage the hardware. Please see the answers to [the aforementioned question](https://superuser.com/questions/1512837/installing-a-second-os-carries-a-risk-of-data-loss-even-your-pcs-user-manual-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have chosen systems available to ship to Brazil today and assume that you are using USD rather than Brazilian Reals. I was able to match and exceed your minimum specs easily with a budget of 2.2K USD.

---

### [MSI GF75 9SC-278 | $1,279.95 + 87.08 International Shipping](https://www.newegg.com/global/br-en/p/2WC-000C-00HX0?Item=9SIA7ABA8H7863)

[image]

Features MSI's magnesium-aluminium alloy which is excellent both for weight and head dissipation. I own an MSI and have never heard of multi-boot issues with the manufacturer as they typically make customization of hardware and software relatively painless. I have seen more than a few people install Linux on MSI computers before. Partitioning your hard-drive and then installing another operating system in that partition will certainly not brick your [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). The easiest way to configure multi boot with Linux + Windows will be the guide I have linked in the comment under your question.

---

### Matched and exceeded specs

- i7-**9**750**H**
- NVIDIA GTX 1650
- **16GB** DDR4-**2333**
- 512 GB **M.2 PCIe NVMe SSD** + 1TB HDD
- Ships **Windows 10** pre-installed
- **Brushed Magnesium-Aluminium Alloy finish**

MSI laptops are usually configured for instant access to SSD, HDD, WiFi Card Module, and battery so I see no issues for storage upgrades if you need it. If you upgrade storage I would endorse buying an M.2 to SATA adapter and switching the existing SSD to secondary.

As for any potential lack of knowledge or being out of the loop with GPUs, I can assure you that the GTX 1650 benchmarks a modest 8% higher in terms of effective speed according to [benchmarks](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1650-Mobile-Max-Q-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1050-Ti/m790279vs3649), meeting and exceeding your graphical requirements.

---

Finally **if you would like a full comprehensive lists of laptops** meeting your requirements and available for shipping to Brazil or would like to push the price further down, [**here is a link to my search query.**](https://www.newegg.com/global/br-en/p/pl?N=101687435%20600003982%20601303722%20601312452%20601323887%20601343206%20601205664%20601206490%20601206491%20601285496%20601328394%20601333544%20600555370%20601300077%20600136700%20600337010%20600440394%20601107729%20601183480%20601331008%20601296067%20601296068%20601296069&Order=PRICE). Asus, MSI, and Dell are all fine to dual boot and I don't see any reason Aorus wouldn't either though I have not heard of this company before.

**Regardless, normal user operations done to your hard drive (partitioning, changing bits aka installing OS's) should never have any impact on your BIOS.**

Comment: If you know what you're doing, installing Linux is generally problem-free. ❧ If you're a non-native English speaker installing Linux for the first time based on some outdated YouTube tutorials, and if you're not careful: You won't brick the machine. But there _is_ a risk that you'll accidentally wipe out your Windows partition and will need professional help to get Windows working again. ❧ Therefore, it's wise to advise at least a bit of caution. :) ❧ Please see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1512837/#1512850), which discusses the risks in more detail.

Comment: Buying laptops from others countries is really annoying for brazilians. Unfortunately we need to pay high tax to get products that costs at least $1000 (+60% including postage).The best alternative that I can get high quality products like MSI GF75 is buying as a second hand, paying much better values which are the same as they are in USA by Mercado Libre. For $1200 I can buy this laptop NOW! I would like to know how you reach the conclusion( where you have seen people installing Linux on MSI laptops,for example) to recommend me this laptop. Unlike the expensive Dell XPS,I can't found any Linu

Comment: ...I can't found any Linux drivers for GF75 model in MSI's site. Thank you!

Comment: Linux support for drivers is usually pretty good for **common consumer** internal parts (like the [Killer Ethernet/Wifi](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/linux-support/) found in most MSI, [Nvidia GPUs](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/146629/en-us), CPU ([here is another laptop running Linux with same CPU](https://system76.com/laptops/oryx))). Sometimes small things like backlight or special key functions need a bit more tinkering in the operating system for it to work. Usually Linux should install all the drivers on it's own during the initial install.

Comment: @Bennett Yeo In fact! I had some experience using Ubuntu Linux on my old PC(dual boot with Windows 7). Then I bought a new USB keyboard (Cougar 700K) ,so when I pressed specific keys to change the mode,the system freezes. Using Windows in the same PC, suddenly the system restarts. Conclusion: the old PC doesn't supports USB keyboards(advanced firmwares) with dual boot system. It drives me crazy!

Comment: This isn't the normal behavior of something not supported by a system, that sounds more like a driver bug. Having two partitions of different data should not cause problems like this. Usually when a device isn't supported, the system will not recognize the device or respond to it beyond knowing some unknown device was plugged in.

Comment: Wow! 3 fans! System76 and Purism Librem are amazing laptops. It's extremely difficult to me buying these laptops. I can't even find any information about them in Brazil. I think these laptops are the best to run Linux distros. Thank you again for the suggestion! This specific model I've never read about before.

Comment: I'll try the same keyboard in my new laptop. If it happens again I'll report it to you. Perhaps the driver doesn't recognize the system in some functions I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

MSI GL63 or if you're looking for a thinner laptop, then MSI GS65 Stealth.

I had a triple booted lenovo B460e (Win7 + Ubuntu + CentOS). I'm having a dual booted HP elitebook 840-G3 Core-i5 laptop (Win10 + Ubuntu). So I hope all the latest models of Lenovo Legion series and HP Omen series laptops support dual/triple/quad boot without any issues.

Comment: Do you hope too that Dell G5 will dual,triple,quad boot without any issues? I like the finish of the Dell laptops and the possibilities to get new battery in the future.

Comment: @J-Mello: All laptops can do multi-boot; you need not worry about that. One valid question is whether or not Linux has good driver support for the machine's hardware. Bennett [writes](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/which-laptops-are-appropriate-to-set-a-dual-boot-systemwindows-and-linux#comment20603_12584) that this is usually not much of a problem with modern consumer-grade PCs. I'm not up to date on these things; hopefully Bennett is not mistaken.